# Magento: why is example.com/product-vragen not working even though "frontName" is turned to product-vragen?

Tags: php, magento, module, controller, config

I'm fairly new to Magento Modules and I've been following the devdoc on their site. I've been trying to display my module for Magento. However, I can't seem to get the URL working. Where in my code did I take the wrong turn? I've created IndexController, Example_ProductQA module and the config.xml.

The module is showing up in my admin/advanced module area! It's purely the url that's not working.

app/code/local/Example/ProductQA/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Example_ProductQA_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }
}
?>
```

app/etc/modules/Example_ProductQA.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Example_ProductQA>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Example_ProductQA>
</modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Example/ProductQA/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- The root node for Magento module configuration -->
<config>

    <modules>

        <Example_ProductQA>

            <version>0.1.0</version>

        </Example_ProductQA>

    </modules>

    <frontend>

        <routers>

            <productqa>

                <use>standard</use>
                <args>

                    <module>Example_ProductQA</module>
                    <frontName>product-vragen</frontName>

                </args>

            </productqa>

        </routers>

    </frontend>

</config>
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: Edited. I hope the question is correct this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, my bad. Rsync wasn't turned on.

Answer (score 1):

As we have checked your code , you have not mention layout code . So
please replace your config.xml file by this code

app/code/local/Example/ProductQA/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_ProductQA>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Example_ProductQA>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <productqa>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Example_ProductQA</module>
                    <frontName>product-vragen</frontName>
                </args>
            </productqa>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productqa>
                    <file>productqa.xml</file>
                </productqa>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <productqa>
                <class>Example_ProductQA_Block</class>
            </productqa>
        </blocks>

    </global>
</config>
```

also please check layout. your layout  file w'll be like that -

app/design/frontend/default{{packapage name }}/ default{{your theme
}}/productqa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <productqa_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="productqa/productqa" name="productqa"
template="productqa/productqa.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </productqa_index_index>
</layout>
```